# how to run a code in __init__.py

Tags: python

In `src/webprofiles/__init__.py` I have

```
def match(string)
```

Now how can I make a call to this match from `src/python.py, which contains

```
from webprofiles import *

for x in text
    a= webprofiles.match(x)
```

Its giving me an error

```
NameError: global name 'webprofiles' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use from import form, you must call function without module prefix.
just call the functions and attributes via their names.

```
from webprofiles import *

for x in text:
    a= match(x)
```

but i suggest to DO NOT use wildcard('*') imports.
use this instead:

```
from webprofiles import match

for x in text:
    a= match(x)
```

Comment: May be the name of the file is not correct, make sure you have a file named:__init__.py in the webprofiles directory

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `from x impoort *` means that everything will be imported, in effect, into the global namespace. What you want is either `import webprofiles` followed by `webprofiles.match` or `from webprofiles import *` followed by a call to plain `match`

Comment: thanx import webprofiles followed by webprofiles.match worked but from webprofiles import * followed by a plain match gave an error!!

Answer (score 1):

Just import webprofiles, not *:

```
import webprofiles

for x in text
    a = webprofiles.match(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there seems to me 2 files and you want to run a file which imports the methods contained in  an other file:

```
import /webprofiles/init


init.match(x)
```

after modifiying your question:

```
import /webprofiles/__init__


__init__.match(x)
```

btw when you import something:

```
import my_file #(file.py)

my_file.quick_sort(x)
```

^^^^^^ you have to call myfile as you call normally an object

```
from my_file import *
#that is read as from my_file import everything
#so now you can use the method quick_sort() without calling my_file
quick_sort(x)
```

Comment: Google `__init__.py`, it's a standard file used in packages and has nothing to do with constructors.